# using 3rd party library (libconfig) with Qt (C++)

Tags: c++, c, qt, name-mangling, libconfig

I'm having trouble getting a third party library (libconfig++) to work in Qt.

When compiling in Qt, I get error messages such as:

```
undefined reference to `_imp___ZN9libconfig6ConfigC1Ev'
undefined reference to `_imp___ZN9libconfig6Config8readFileEPKc'
undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK9libconfig6Config5writeEP6_iobuf'
```

etc.

In my .pro file, I have:

```
LIBS += -L$$PWD/libconfig/lib -lconfig++
```

And I've added libconfig++.dll and libconfig++.lib to the correct folder.

This project uses another 3rd party library (in a similar way) successfully so I don't think it's a syntax or include problem.

It seems like it might be a C++ name mangling issue? How can I confirm this?

Right now, I build the library in VS 2008 (I've tried building it both as a dynamic and static library, neither work). I think I've been able to do this in the past with other libraries. Is there some flag in VS that I'm not setting correctly?

Thanks

Comment: Have you confirmed that the library and its path appear correctly in the build output?

Comment: Yes, the path appears correctly. I have everything identical to how I've included the other 3rd party library and the code works fine if I removed references to libconfig in my code. I strongly suspect name-mangling, but I don't know how to confirm that this is the problem (or how to fix it)

Comment: Configuration Properties->C/C++->Advanced->Compile As set to Compile As C++ Code (/TP)? libconfig set as a dependency (Project->Project Dependencies...)?

Comment: How are you compiling the application that uses that library ? The name mangling scheme indicates you are compiling with MinGW/gcc Qt libraries, and you can't mix a C++ library compiled with VC++ with it (a C library would be ok).

Comment: Are you sure the .dll name shouldn't be `config++.dll`?  Note the different library naming conventions between Unix-like and Windows. On Unix-like the library .so files start with `lib` prefix, which is not included in the `-l` linker option. On Windows, .dll files do not have implicit `lib` prefix. In other words, Unixy `libconfig++.so` file would typically be `config++.dll` on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

If your library is called "libconfig++.lib" you might have to change

```
LIBS += -L$$PWD/libconfig/lib -lconfig++
```

to

```
LIBS += -L$$PWD/libconfig/lib -llibconfig++
```